# $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{10000000000000000} \frac{1}{n}$

Tags: calculus, summation

How does wolfram alpha solve $$\sum\limits_{n=1}^{10000000000000000} \frac{1}{n}\approx 37.4186$$so quickly? It solved it in like 3 seconds is there a equation or something

Comment: It probably uses some known approximation of the expression.

Comment: It's an approximation, probably using the fact that this diverges like $\log n$.

Comment: As an addition to @GregoryGrant's comment: $$ \ln(10000000000000000) = 36.8413615.$$

Comment: why do't you use the scientific notation?

Answer (score 20):

One can prove that

$$\sum_{n=1}^N \frac{1}{n} = \ln(N) + \gamma + O(1/N)$$

where $\gamma$ is the Euler-Mascheroni constant, which is defined by this equation and has been tabulated in quite some detail (it is about $0.577216$). The first term comes from noticing that $\sum_{n=1}^N \frac{1}{n}$ is a Riemann sum for calculating $\int_1^N \frac{1}{y} dy = \ln(N)$. The other two terms are corrections.

From this it follows that

$$\sum_{n=1}^{10^{16}} \frac{1}{n} \approx \ln \left ( 10^{16} \right ) + \gamma$$

where the error is something like $10^{-16}/2$, because one can actually prove that the $O(1/N)$ term is less than $1/(2N)$.

Comment: Since $\frac{1}{2n+1}\le H_n-\ln n-\gamma\le \frac{1}{2n}$ the error is about $\approx \frac{1}{2}\cdot 10^{-16}$.

Comment: @anon It actually goes the other way, it should be less than $10^{-16}/2$. At any rate it's not that important when requesting only 4 digits of accuracy.

Comment: @anon how did you get such an equality?

Comment: I remembered it from MathWorld. You get a $\frac{1}{2n}$ in the Euler-Maclaurin expansion of $H_n$ as well.

Comment: @JefLaga The basic idea is that $\sum_{n=1}^N \frac{1}{n}$ is a Riemann sum for calculating $\int_1^N \frac{1}{y} dy$ with $\sum_{n=1}^N \frac{1}{n}$. $\gamma$ is the first correction term.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, in short there is an equation. When you're summing a continuously differentiable function, you have "Euler Summation",
$$ \sum_{y \leq n \leq x} f(n) = \int_y^x f(t)dt + \int_y^x (t - \lfloor t \rfloor)f'(t)dt + f(x)(\lfloor x\rfloor - x) - f(y)(\lfloor y \rfloor - y).$$
Applied to $f(x) = \frac{1}{x}$, you get
$$\sum_{m \leq n} \frac{1}{m} = \log n + \gamma + O(1/n),$$
where $\gamma$ is the Euler Mascheroni constant.

To check,
$$\ln(10000000000000000) + \gamma = 36.8413615 + 0.5772156649 = 37.4185771649.$$

Answer (score 2):

we can use the prime numbers in geometric series as follow
$$1+1/2+1/3+1/4+1/5+1/6+1/7+...=1+1/2+1/4+1/8+1/16+...1/3+1/9+1/27+...+1/5+1/25+1/125+...$$
$$1+\frac{1/2}{1-1/2}+\frac{1/3}{1-1/3}+\frac{1/5}{1-1/5}+....$$

Comment: You can't be talking about $\sum\frac{1}{p-1}$ over all primes, because that doesn't depend on $n$, and it diverges anyway. If you're talking about $\sum_{p\le n}\frac{1}{p-1}$, this is $\sim \ln\ln n+M+N$ by Merten's second theorem, where $M$ is the Meissel-Mertens constant and $N=\sum_p\frac{1}{p(p-1)}$ (which probably has a name but I couldn't find it). This grows far too slowly to be used as any sort of approximation for $H_n$. It was a good initial guess though.

Comment: @anon yes I accept with you , Thanks for your comments

Comment: I don't think you need to delete, because it is a clever idea and the fact that the idea doesn't work out (and why) is interesting information that others might like to know.